# Проверка возвращаемого результата

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Есть такая функция

```cpp
HRESULT convert(type1 from, type2 &to) {
  .......
}
```

Вызывается она всегда в таком виде

```cpp
type2 val2;
HRESULT res = convert(val1, val2);
if (res != S_OK)
  return res;
// Using val2
```

хочется ее во что-то обернуть, чтобы вызов выполнялся по такой схеме

```cpp
type2 val2 = WRAP_CONVERT(val1);
```

где `WRAP_CONVERT` что-то типа такого

```cpp
#define WRAP_CONVERT(x) type2 a; \
  HREULT res = convert(x, a); \
  if (res != S_OK) return res; \
  a
```

но значение `a` так возвратить не получится, а двойное использование такого макроса приводит к повторному объявлению переменных

Comment: Просто оберните тело макроса в пару разных скобок -- `({ type2 a; HRESULT res = convert(x, a); if (res != S_OK) return res; a;})` Переменные `a` и `res` в каждом блоке будут локальными в блоке `{ ...}` . Значение `a` будет результатом всего выражения `({...})`

Answer (score 2):

```
type2 WRAP_CONVERT(type1 from)
{ 
    type2 to;
    if (convert(from, to) != S_OK) throw(.....);
    return to;
}
```

Так? Исключение - сами допишите, какое нужно...

```
pair<type2, HRESULT> WRAP_CONVERT(type1 from)
{
    type2 to;
    pair<type2, HRESULT> r;
    r.second = convert(from, to);
    r.first = to;
    return r;
}
```

Для тех, кто не понимает, что значит обработка ошибок и что такое С++...

```
type2 WRAP_CONVERT(type1 from)
{ 
    type2 to;
    convert(from, to);
    return to;
}
```

Comment: Так то оно так, но тогда в вызывающем коде нужно будет организовать отлов исключений и конвертацией их обратно в HRESULT. Не хотелось бы исключений

Comment: Ну возвращайте два значения (см. ответ). Только вот для того исключения в С++ и придуманы, чтоб ошибки обрабатывать! А если вам лень - то берите третий вариант и считайте "А, и так сойдет!"...

Comment: в том-то и дело, что ошибка мне нужна и проглатывать ее нельзя. Более того, при наличии ошибки вызывающий метод должен именно ее и возвратить. Так, что третий  вариант однозначно нет. Второй вариант ничем не лучше моего изначального.

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, что вам нужно... :( Заменить нормальный вызов опасным макросом? да сколько угодно, только просьба - уберите тэг С++, в С++ так дела не делают... Передача в `convert` по ссылке еще не делает ваш код кодом С++. Вы вообще отдаете себе отчет, что в вашем варианте отличить правильный результат от ошибки - в общем случае невозможно?

Comment: У меня COM-сервер и я не имею право выпускать исключений за пределы вызывающего метода. И чем макрос опасен?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю лучше передавать в WRAP_CONVERT название переменной var2

```cpp
#define WRAP_CONVERT(x, var2) type2 var2; \
  HRESULT res = convert(x, var2); \
  if (res != S_OK) return res;
```

или (чтобы `;` обязательно было ставить после `WRAP_CONVERT(...)` )

```cpp
#define WRAP_CONVERT(x, var2) \
  type2 var2; \
  do { \
      HRESULT res = convert(x, var2); \
      if (res != S_OK) return res; \
  } \
  while(false) \
```

Тогда вызывать можно так

```
WRAP_CONVERT(val1, val2);
\\ использование val2
\\ ...
return val2;
```

Comment: Это уже ближе к тому, что я хочу.

Comment: Кстати, цикл лишний достаточно `{...}`

Comment: кажется там `;` тогда не обязательно ставить

Comment: Не обязательно. Но и не запрещено